# Can someone explain me why we do not use "the" in this situation?

Tags: definite-article

The sentence is:

> Actually, I'd prefer somewhere warmer and by the sea. I think Corfu
> would be nice. **We might get sunshine there.**

As I understand we do not use "***the*** sunshine" because there of "might" that refers to a doubt. Am I correct?

Comment: What is the context and the source here?

Comment: No, that is not the reason. The third sentence refers to sunshine in general as a type of weather, rather than _the sunshine_ on a particular occasion. "We were sitting on the beach in the sunshine."

Comment: Ok, I understand, thank you so much

Answer (score 2):

As Kate mentioned, the reason we don't use "the" isn't because of the doubt, it is because 'sunshine' refers to the generic type of weather.

For instance, you would say "I love sunshine", meaning you like the weather in general, but you could also say "I love the sunshine" if you are currently in the sunshine.

Comment: Ditto for **rain, money, beer** and much else. The first refers to the prospect; the second to the experience.

Comment: But you would say "Things get wet in **the** rain". Why?

Comment: I kind of wonder if this should be its own question